# Display bands in excel charts

Tags: excel, charts

I'd like to implement bands in an Excel chart, is that possible?
[image: Bollinger Bands]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like a candlestick chart with hi-low lines as fat as the up-down bars.

Plot your data. Plot the open-high-low-close as line chart series on the primary axes and the upper, middle, and lower lines on the secondary axis, but then delete the secondary horizontal and vertical axes so all data is plotted against the primary axes.

Select on of the first four series (OHLC) and add up-down bars and high-low lines (Excel 2013-2016: Chart Tools > Design tab > Add Chart Element dropdown; earlier versions on Chart Tools > Layout tab). Format the up-down bars to show the colors you want (you have red and green, which sucks for the 8.5% or so of your male audience who experience problems with color vision). Format the high-low lines to use the line color of your outer bands (looks like dark blue) and use a fat line, several points wide to match the up-down bars.

Finally, format the OHLC series to use no markers and no line.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming this is the type of banding you want to know how to do. Hope this helps.

Dynamic banding:

1) Add Fields for Minimum and Maximum Horizontal Band Range
2) Setup Your Data and Add 2 Series with Formulas
3) Create an Excel Stacked Column Chart or Excel Stacked Bar Chart
4) Change the Inventory Data Series to a Line Chart
5) Change the Fill Color of the No Fill Series
6) Chart Clean Up

Comment: You may be right pnuts. There are different types of bands and I just chose one type to explain. Without knowing more information about the types of bands the OP wants, I feel we may be on a guessing game.